# Integrals problem

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that;
> $\int_0^{\pi/4}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_0^{\pi/8}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_0^{\pi/16}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_0^{\pi/32}f\left(x\right)dx=\dots$
>
> Show that
> $f\left(\sqrt[3]{t}e^t\right)=-\left(3t\right)f\left(\sqrt[3]{t}e^t\right)$
> for infinitely many $t$.

Okay so i'm very bad with integral and i was wondering how would i approach this questions? are there any tips or ricks to keep in mind so in the future it will be more intuitive for me?